# How to implement Dispatcher BeginInvoke for simple parse statement?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a background thread and a main thread for a loop in my C# application.

On this background thread I have to access Text from the UI and Parse it to be used in conditional statements as seen below:

```
        int i = 0;

        int loopNum = int.Parse(Loop_Number.Text); //< What I need to access

        if (loopNum > 0)
        {
            while (i < loopNum)
            {
                //DoStuff
            }
        }
```

Problem being the above statements are being run in the background thread not the main UI thread. So the program throws an InvalidOperationException for that int.Parse statement.

Exception has this information:

Additional information: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

So being that I only have a UI thread and this thread run temporarily how can I access Loop_Number.Text within this background thread.

I have tried the below code:

```
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { int loopNum = int.Parse(Loop_Number.Text); }));
```

but then loopNum is out of context for the conditional statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer, which will resolve the immediate problem, is that you need to use `Invoke()` instead of `BeginInvoke()`:

```
string text = (string)Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Loop_Number.Text);

int loopNum = int.Parse(text);
```

Now, that said, there are signs in your question that you're simply doing it all wrong. :(

First, you should not need to access a UI object directly at all. I.e. from the exception you report, the `Loop_Number` variable presumably is a reference to some WPF control, like a `TextBox`. Instead, you should be following some kind of data binding pattern, like MVVM, in which you have a non-UI object which has a property bound to the UI control, and which receives the desired number.

Doing it that way, not only would the property be set in the UI thread, allowing the value to be accessible elsewhere (such as in a different thread) without invoking on the UI thread, you can make the property have the type `int` and WPF will convert from the text for you. You wouldn't even need to call `int.Parse()` at all.

Second, while it's hard to say for sure without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing clearly what you're doing, I doubt it's really a good idea for the thread to be retrieving the value at all. Instead, the value is something that your UI thread should have retrieved at the point in time that it decided it needed to start this background operation, and the value should be *passed* to the background operation somehow (stored in a data structure specific to the operation, passed to an `async` method that represents the operation, etc.).

Bottom line: while the code at the top of this answer will address your specific concern, I doubt it's really the way this code (whatever it is) ought to be written. You should probably consider revisting your design, so that it works more smoothly, without the need for calling `Invoke()` at all.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, I solved the problem very simply by using a field for loopNum.